# How do I parse a nested array in a nested JSON object in Golang?

Tags: json, go

I have a JSON:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "values": [
                [
                    {
                        "id": "11",
                        "keys": [
                            {
                                "id": "111"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to parse "values" and "keys" into structs, but I don't known what type should i use in "Data"?:

```
type Value struct {
    Id   string `json:"id"`
    Keys []Key  `json:"keys"`
}
type Key struct {
    Id string `json:"id"`
}
type Result struct {
    Data []Data `json:"data"`
}
type Data struct {
    Id     int      `json:"id"`
    Values []???? `json:"values"`
}
```

I would be grateful for any help. Thanks.

Comment: start from inside and create structures separately and call all substructures from one generic structure. (This is the traditional approach.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look carefully at your json. you have an array in an array...

```
...
    "values": [
                    [...
```

If this is intended then the type of values is:

```
[][]Value
```

to represent the two arrays, else remove the array nesting and it becomes:

```
[]Value
```

**Runnable Example:** https://play.golang.org/p/UUqQR1KSwB

Answer (score -1):

```
    type Basic struct {
        ID string `json:"id"`
    }

    type Inner struct {
        ID string `json:"id"`
        Keys []Basic `json:"keys"`
    }

    type Middle struct {
        ID int `json:"id"`
        Values []Inner `json:"values"`
    }

    type Final struct {
        Data []Middle `json:"data"`
    }
```